# Prepopulating a Form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to populate a form in a new window using JQuery but I cant seem to get it to work, it currently opens the new window as desired. But any attempts to populate the form failts.

```
$( "body" ).delegate( ".propose", "click",function() {  
    var url = './prop_form.php';    
    var win = window.open(url, 'Marketing Docs', 'directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,width=500,height=600');

    $(win).find('input[name=vrm]').val('x');

    if (win.focus) { win.focus(); } 
});
```

The script should populate a text input called vrm.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but shouldn't it be `input[name="vrm"]` instead of `input[name=vrm]`?

Comment: No change, the selectors work fine on the same window.

Comment: I am guessing that your code for setting the value executes before the window loads fully. Just add delay for 2 or 3 seconds, then try setting the value. If this doesn't work then at-least we can rule out one possibility.

Comment: You can also debug the value of this part $(win).find('input[name=vrm]') ,after the window load if it is fetching the text box

Comment: It works with jQuery's load event: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I got it to write to the input but then it blanks the input afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated (again)**, I finally got it working after using load event:

```
      $("body").delegate(".propose", "click", function () {
            var url = './prop_form.php';

            var win = window.open(url, 'Marketing Docs', 'menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,width=500,height=600');

            $(win).load( function() {  

                $(win.document).find('input[name="vrm"]').val('x');

                $(win.document).find('input[name="vrm"]').focus();

            });
      });
```

Alternative with `setTimeout` method

```
     $("body").delegate(".propose", "click", function () {
        var url = './prop_form.php';

        var win = window.open(url, 'Marketing Docs', 'menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,width=500,height=600');

        setTimeout(function() { 
             $(win.document).find('input[name="vrm"]').val('x');, 2000); });
      });
```

I tested the code using Chrome and noticed that one of the `window.open` parameter attributes is obsolete: [directories=yes|no|1|0](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). Once I removed that parameter the `window.open` method started working.